# ADB doesn't see my tablet

Tags: android, adb, tablet

I'm trying to use my tablet for compile with Eclipse but ADB doesn't see my devices. I have driver and I checked it a lot times. Reinstall ADB and Google USB drive from eclipse but the result is same.

Comment: is USB debugging enabled?

Comment: i don't i can conclude anything else with your info...

Comment: What tablet model, what operating system, are you using? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to 
**Settings > Storage > USB Computer Condition**. Two checkboxes: MTP and PTP. **Uncheck** both.

You can see USB "Computer Condition" top right side after search box.